# Can't Update Room database item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to update a column of an item in a room database but the item isn't updating.

My Entity:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "order_summary_table")
    data class SummaryItem(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "quantity")
    var quantity: Int = -1,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_price")
    var price: Int
    ) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var itemId: Long = 0
    }
```

Here is my Dao:

```
    @Update
    fun update(summaryItem: SummaryItem)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM order_summary_table WHERE itemId = :key")
    suspend fun get(key: Long): SummaryItem?
```

Function in the ViewModel. I'm using Kotlin Coroutines for database operations. My database has 3 columns: quantity, name and price. Here I wrote a function to update the quantity column of an item in the database:

```
   fun saveEditedItem(quantity: Int, summaryItemKey: Long) {
      coroutineScope.launch {
           val item = database.get(summaryItemKey)
           val editedItem = SummaryItem(quantity, item!!.name, item.price)
           updateSummaryItem(editedItem)
       }
   }

   private suspend fun updateSummaryItem(summaryItem: SummaryItem) {
      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
          database.update(summaryItem)
      }
   }
```

Fragment.kt file, Here I set an OnClickListener to update the item on button click but the item isn't getting updated.

```
   val quantityText = binding.editQuantityText
   binding.saveButton.setOnClickListener {
        val editTextValue = quantityText.text
        val quantity = Integer.parseInt(editTextValue.toString())
        viewModel.saveEditedItem(quantity, arguments.summaryItemKey)
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's not updating? The database entry is not updating? The LiveData object you're observing is not updating? More info required

Comment: Please include your Entity

Comment: Can you validate that the primary key is the same with the one which you are trying to update?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on  line `updateSummaryItem(editedItem)`, run in debug. What is the value of **itemId**? My guess is 0 and that you need to set it to the value of  **summaryItemKey** or **item.itemId** (should be the same value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think there is 2 ways.

1.in `saveEditedItem(...)` fun add itemId PrimaryKey

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    val item = database.get(summaryItemKey)
    val editedItem = SummaryItem(quantity, item!!.name, item.price)
    editedItem.itemId = item.itemId
    updateSummaryItem(editedItem)
}
```

2.update item itself.

```
coroutineScope.launch {
        val item = database.get(summaryItemKey)
        item.quantity = //newQuantity
        item.name = // newName
        item.price = // newPrice
        updateSummaryItem(item)
    }
```